# How to keep a button closed on opening the page

Tags: html

I have a button which I would like to keep closed when the user opens the page but for some reason it keeps opening when the page is opened.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<main>
</main>
    <button><h4><b>Example</b></h4></button>
<font face="caslon", style="font-weight:normal">
<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    </font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "closed" and "open" for a button?

Comment: Don't use the `<font>` tag; it's deprecated. Use `<style>` or an external CSS file instead.

Comment: @arkascha by open it means the button is active displaying the text i want it to be inactive so the text is not showing

Comment: So it actually is _not_ the button you want "open" or "closed" but the paragraph. Why don't you say so in your question?

Comment: Actually you take no step at all to close that paragraph in the first place. So why do you expect it to be closed (hidden, actually)? You need to close it first. So for example close it when loading the page by handing over a callback function doing so to the `onLoad` event. Or you initialize the page's style accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply first apply `p {display: none;}` and when user clicks on button it will show your paragraph.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p.togglable").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
p.togglable {
  display: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: caslon;
}

button {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Example</button>
<p class="togglable">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
```

Comment: so add it to this bit? <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

Comment: when i use it it also hides other paragraphs on the page is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: @AEON Yes, directly select it using class or ID